# How to change the sort order of a specific folder in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, sort

I want all the files in my Downloads folder to be sorted by modification date, but all other folders, and files in other partitions to be sorted by name. How can I do that?

Edit: I want Nautilus to remember these orders for each folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go in **Downloads**, click on **View Options** and select **By Modification Date**:

[image: nautilus]

In other folders, do the same thing, but select **By Name**. Nautilus seems to remember this selection/sort order for each directory (I use GNOME nautilus 3.8.2).

Comment: I know how to choose sort by Name and Modification date, but my problem is that nautilus does not remember the sort order. What should I do?

Comment: @Ali Which is your nautilus version?  You should update to nautilus 3.8.2. As I said, Nautilus 3.8.2 does remember the sort order

Comment: **Nautilus 3.10.1** doesn't have that **Down Arrow** (or the **Cog** for Menu) in the toolbar, although you get the same Sort options in the standard View menu.